# Changing color of cells on calendar

Tags: android, events, colors, calendar, caldroid

I have learned that you cant add events to the default calendarview (it just gets handled in the user's default calendar) so I am using caldroid https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/blob/master/README.md which has been pretty helpful with documentation so far, but I am lost when it comes to one thing.

What I want to do is change the color of any date that has an event. The documentation says to make a drawable and put it in the cell, but I am even more lost on how to do that, so I think changing the color of the cell would be easier.

My current code looks like this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment;
import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidListener;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class CalendarActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendarLayout, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();



    final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
            String text = "month: " + month + " year: " + year;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Long click " + date.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Caldroid view is created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };

    caldroidFragment.setCaldroidListener(listener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calendar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I have checked here [Change Color of cell of grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315714/change-color-of-cell-of-grid) here [Using an intent to edit calendar event doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072275/using-an-intent-to-edit-calendar-event-doesnt-work?rq=1) here [Caldroid does not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878235/caldroid-does-not-refresh) and here [I want to change font color of events on calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628552/i-want-to-change-font-color-of-events-on-calendar) and I am not sure what to do.

I know I can change the color of a date with         caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.blue, blueDate); but I am not sure how to make that correspond to a date which has an event. If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, happy mothers day!

I have just stumbled across this code and am in the process of implementing it.

@Override
        public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatter.format(date),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
        String text = "month: " + month + " year: " + year;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Long click " + formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis()+60000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "hiii");
        startActivity(intent);
        caldroidFragment.refreshView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
        if (caldroidFragment.getLeftArrowButton() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Caldroid view is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

};final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
        String text = "month: " + month + " year: " + year;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClickDate(Date date, View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Long click " + formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();Calendar cal =     Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis()+60000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "hiii");
        startActivity(intent);
        caldroidFragment.refreshView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaldroidViewCreated() {
        if (caldroidFragment.getLeftArrowButton() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Caldroid view is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect listener on month scrolling in android times square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764521/detect-listener-on-month-scrolling-in-android-times-square)

Comment: @CTB I know its too late. Did you implement some work around? Do you need help regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void setCustomResourceForDates() {


        Map<Date, Drawable> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.clear();

        // Put elements to the map

        for (int i = 0; i < offdays.size(); i++) {

            hm.put(ParseDate(offdays.get(i)), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundedred));

        }


        if (caldroidFragment != null) {

            if (offdays.size() > 0) {
                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDates(hm);
            }

        }

        caldroidFragment.refreshView();
    }
```

Comment: parsedate methiod

Comment: public Date ParseDate(String date_str) {
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            date = format.parse(date_str);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }